HTML5 Server-Sent Events: new EventSource as variable
I am working with ESP8266 moduls in Wifi-Station Mode. Each new ESP8266 module is assigned a different IP address by the wifi router. That's why I need the Ip addresses as Javascript variable, but that doesn't work:
    let ip = location.host;
    let str1 = 'http://';
    let str3 = '/see';
    
    let strIpAdress = str1+ip+str3;                  // doesn't work
    //let strIpAdress = 'http://192.168.178.47/sse'; // works!

    var source = new EventSource(strIpAdress); 
    console.log(strIpAdress);                        // http://192.168.178.47/sse


I have also tried in JavaScript String Object Format, but also without success.
Does a fixed IP address always have to be specified to prevent manipulation?
Is there a solution?

Did you log what location.host returns?

Yes: "192.168.178.47"

If you want to be a programmer you have to be able to see the smallest of details by yourself without asking for help.  You tested manually with /sse but your code uses /see instead.  This kind of problem is easy to spot if you have the right aptitude for programming.

It did not work with the variable. The expression must always be fixed at runtime.
Nevertheless, I was able to solve the problem because the path can also be specified relatively:
const str3 = “/sse”;
var source = new EventSource(str3);  

This works perfectly!
